# Output values are incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x

The variable d_f is a 2d array as required but contains values only upto (9,9). All other values are zero. Also the values that are obtained seems to be incorrect. Is there something wrong in the way I have assigned values to d_f?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_o = 0.5
y_o = 0                   
z_o = 0

#Define flash position 
x_f = np.linspace(-0.4,0.4,10)
y_f = np.linspace(-0.4,0.4,10)
z_f =  0

# Define angle of inclination 
i_A =np.pi/2    # pi/2 means edge on         
c = 3*pow(10,8) # A.U/minute
r = 0.5 # A.U
n_s = 360

# 1) Take 360 phi values and compute t values
phi = np.linspace(0,2*359.9*np.pi/360,n_s)
d_f_o = np.sqrt(pow((x_f-x_o),2)+ pow((y_f-y_o),2)+ pow((z_f-z_o),2))
x_r = r*np.cos(phi)
y_r = r*np.sin(phi)
z_r = 0  # Circle is in the x-y plane
d_f = np.zeros(shape=(100,n_s))
d_o = np.zeros(shape=(n_s))
d_p =  np.zeros(shape=(100,n_s))

for j in np.arange(len(x_f)):
    for k in np.arange(len(y_f)):
        for i in np.arange(0,n_s,1):
            d_f[j][k] = (np.sqrt(pow((x_f[j]-x_r[i]),2)+ pow((y_f[k]-y_r[i]),2)+ pow((z_f-z_r),2)))
            d_o[i] = ((1-np.cos(phi[i]))*r*np.sin(i_A))
```

Comment: the dimensions of `x_f` and `y_f` is 10 x 10 so it writes to only (9,9), what is the dimension of d_f you were expecting?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question such as: What is the program doing? What do the variables stand for and what are you expecting as output from the calculation? What do you mean the values are incorrect? What would the correct values look like?

Comment: You should try to make your title as specific as possible to help attract the right attention.  Almost all programming issues involve *incorrect output values*...

Answer (score 0):

`x_f` and `y_f` dimensions are 10 x 10. Maybe you wanted to do this instead?

```
for j in range(100):
    for k in range(n_s):
        for i in np.arange(0, n_s, 1):
            d_f[j][k] = (np.sqrt(pow((x_f[j%10] - x_r[i]), 2) + pow((y_f[k%10] - y_r[i]), 2) + pow((z_f - z_r), 2)))
            d_o[i] = ((1 - np.cos(phi[i])) * r * np.sin(i_A))
```

Comment: for each x_f and y_f value I wanted 360 d_f values. So I guess I am not assigning the values properly to d_f. How should I have done to obtain this?

Comment: `x_f = np.linspace(-0.4,0.4,360)`? You didn't assign `d_f` to `x_f` or `y_f` anywhere in your code and you set `d_f` as 100x360.... very unclear what you're trying to do